# how to fix this issue..?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my complete code.I have used "for" to copy the table n-times.But A function "copy(Selector)" runs only at 1st table and not working in subsequent copied tables.Am a beginner and help me out with solution or alter the code.

And This is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3shjhu98/3/

```
<!Doctype HTML>
<html>

<head>

  <style>
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse
    }

    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      height: 100%;
    }

    p001 {
      border: none;
    }

    table {
      counter-reset: section;
    }

    .count:before {
      counter-increment: section;
      content: counter(section);
    }
  </style>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var num, i, c;
    j = 1;

    function cloneRow() {
      num = document.getElementById("copying number").value;
      for (i = 0; i < num - 1; i++) {
        var row = document.getElementById("rowToClone");
        var table = document.getElementById("tableToModify");
        var clone = row.cloneNode(true);
        clone.id = "newID";
        table.appendChild(clone);
        document.getElementById("Name1").value = "";
        document.getElementById("Name2").value = "";
        document.getElementById("Name3").value = "";
        document.getElementById("Name4").value = "";
      }

      function createRow() {
        var row = document.createElement('tr');
        var col = document.createElement('td');
        var col2 = document.createElement('td');
        row.appendChild(col);
        row.appendChild(col2);
        var table = document.getElementById("tableToModify");
        table.appendChild(row);
      }
    }
  </script>

  <script>
    function copy(selector) {
      var text1 = document.getElementById(selector + "1").value;
      document.getElementById(selector + "2").value = text1;
      var text2 = document.getElementById(selector + "3").value;
      document.getElementById(selector + "4").value = text2;
    }
  </script>

  <body>
    <form>
      <h4>Enter the number of times to be copied</h4>
      <input type="text" id="copying number" placeholder="Enter Here">
      <input type="reset" value="clear">
    </form>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Copy row" onclick="cloneRow()">

    <br><br>

    <table width="100%" id="tableToModify">
      <tbody id="rowToClone">

        <tr>
          <td colspan="5" style="border:2px solid black;height:50px;text-align:center;">header
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td style="height:25px;width:11%;text-align:center;" class="count">Name</td>

          <td colspan="3" style="width:11%;height:100px;text-align:center;">Age</td>
          <td style="width:11%;text-align:center;">Gender</td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

          <td rowspan="3" style="height:100px;">
            <pre>Name  <input type="text" name="Emp name"  placeholder="enter your name"  id="Name1"/><br>
        ID    <input type="id" name="Emp Id" placeholder="enter id" id="Name3" > </pre>
          </td>

          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>

          <td rowspan="3">
            <pre>
          <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="male">MALE</input>
          <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="female">FEMALE</input> <br>  <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="other">OTHER</input>
          </pre>
          </td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="p01">
          <td></td>
          <td colspan="4" style="height:100px"></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="5" style="height:50px;text-align:center;">
            footer</td>

        </tr>

        <tr id="p001">
          <td colspan="10" style="border:1px solid #ffffff;height:150px;"><input type="button" value="Get data" onclick="copy('Name');" />
            <pre><label for="text"> Name : <input type="text" id="Name2"></label>
        <label for="text"> ID   : <input type="id" id="Name4"></label> </pre>

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</head>

</html>
```

Comment: Buddy your html and Js is pretty messed up. Are you aware of Html and Js basic rules. Your html id should be unique and with no space ideally. Major cleanup is required. Also copying new tables, you should create elements with unique Ids, not the copied ones.

Comment: @Reshma it is not working properly

Comment: yeah,  I can understand buddy.bt am a beginner am not completely expertise in js.please update my codings.I ll learn from it.@ PrabodhM

Comment: Pardon me, dude.could you please tell which part is not working...???@NiravJoshi

Comment: You should put `copy(Selector)` inside the for loop if you want to run it X amount of times.

Comment: i tried it too bro bt its not wrkng

Comment: Improved code formatting